# how to keep track of previous value before changing it in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub chkLoop_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkLoop.CheckedChanged
    intValue1 = nudX4.Value
    intValue2 = nudY4.Value
    Dim g As TrigLib.TrigLib = New TrigLib.TrigLib
    ' Make the shape closed by making the last point the same as the first point. 
    If chkLoop.Checked Then
        nudX4.Value = nudX1.Value
        nudY4.Value = nudY1.Value

        lblArea.Text = "Area: " & CInt(g.AreaTriangle(New Point(nudX1.Value, nudY1.Value), New Point(nudX2.Value, nudY2.Value), New Point(nudX3.Value, nudY3.Value)))
    ElseIf chkLoop.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        nudX4.Value = intValue1
        nudY4.Value = intValue2
        lblArea.Text = ""
```

I was trying to store my previous values of point nudX4 and nudY4 in two local variable. But when i uncheck my checkbox the values of nudX4 and nudY4 remain equal to values of nudX1 and nudY1 instead of changing back to previous values.

Please help.

Comment: Think about what's happening there.  You are copying the `Value` properties from `nudX4` and `nudY4` into those variables EVERY time the `Checked` property value changes.  That means that, if you enter the `ElseIf` block, you're simply then copying those same values back again.  If you only want to set the variables when the box is checked then you need to put the code that sets the variable somewhere that it will only be executed when the box is checked.  The issue would have been obvious if you had debugged the code so you should learn how to do that ASAP.

Comment: Thanks...Now I know what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub chkLoop_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkLoop.CheckedChanged
    If chkLoop.Checked Then
        ...
        intValue1 = nudX4.Value
        intValue2 = nudY4.Value
    ElseIf chkLoop.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        nudX4.Value = intValue1
        nudY4.Value = intValue2
       ...
```